# Saving Picker Value null exception cannot convert string to model

Tags: xamarin

I am having an issue with saving of my picker value. I am rewriting old code and i am struggling with saving a picker value. Once I select the picker i have the value but it doesn't go through the getter. I have similar method on other picker it works there perfectly co I dont really understand what is wrong. The only thing is that if you notice the older piece there is the Model property.Position when filling the value. Please see my notes in the code. I have Inotify in the model as advised and in the vm

```
 public class SettingsViewModel : ObservableObject 
{

       private List<CustomTextSize> _textSize = new List<CustomTextSize>();
            private CustomTextSize _selectedTextSize;

        public CustomTextSize SelectedTextSize
                {
                    get => _selectedTextSize; // doesnt go through here 

                    set
                    {
                        if (_selectedTextSize != value && _selectedTextSize != null) 
                        {
                            this.IsBusy = true;
                            SetProperty(ref _selectedTextSize, value);
                            NotificationService.ShowToast("Probíhá ukládání, prosím čekejte");

                            UserSettings newSetting = new UserSettings()
                            {
                                DateSaved = DateTime.Now,
                                OptionId = (int)SettingOption.TextFontSize,
                                Value = value.Position.ToString()
                            };

                            new Thread(new ThreadStart(async () =>
                            {
                                await LangUpDataSaverLoader.SaveUserSettings(newSetting);
                                LangUpDataSaverLoader.LoadUserSettingsAndFillAppValues();
                            })).Start();

                            this.IsBusy = false;
                        }

                    }


                }

    public List<CustomTextSize> TextSize
            {
                get => _textSize;
                set => SetProperty(ref _textSize, value);

            }

       _textSize = FillTextSizeOptions();
                var customSize = _textSize.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Value == LangUpUserCustomSettings.CustomFontSize); // here should be position? But then I am getting that I cannot conevrt int to Model.
                if (customSize != null)
                {

                    _selectedTextSize = customSize;
                }




}
Model

public class CustomTextSize : ObservableObject {

    public int Position { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

Xaml

```
<Picker x:Name="textSize" WidthRequest="300"
                                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"   FontSize="20"
                                 Title="{ grial:Translate A_PickerSizeOfText }"
                              ItemsSource ="{Binding TextSize}" ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Text}" 
                              SelectedItem ="{Binding SelectedTextSize, Mode=TwoWay}"
                            grial:PickerProperties.BorderStyle="Default"
                    BackgroundColor="Transparent" 
                TextColor= "{ DynamicResource ListViewItemTextColor }" >
                            </Picker>

Old piece of code that I am rewrting





Spinner textSizeSpinner = new Spinner(MainActivity.Instance);
                ArrayAdapter textSizeAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(MainActivity.Instance, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerDropDownItem);
                textSizeAdapter.AddAll(FillTextSizeOptions().Select(m => m.Text).ToList());
                textSizeSpinner.Adapter = textSizeAdapter;
                textSizeSpinner.SetBackgroundColor(Color.FromHex("#3680b2").ToAndroid());
                fontSizeStepper.Children.Add(textSizeSpinner);
                initialTextSizeSpinnerPosition = FillTextSizeOptions().FirstOrDefault(m => m.Value == LangUpUserCustomSettings.CustomFontSize).Position; //here is the .Position
                textSizeSpinner.SetSelection(initialTextSizeSpinnerPosition);

protected async void TextSizeSelected(object sender, AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Position != initialTextSizeSpinnerPosition)
            {
                dialog.SetProgressStyle(ProgressDialogStyle.Spinner);
                dialog.SetCancelable(false);
                dialog.SetMessage("Probíhá ukládání, prosím čekejte");
                dialog.Show();

                Spinner spinner = (Spinner)sender;
                Model.UserSettings newSetting = new Model.UserSettings()
                {
                    DateSaved = DateTime.Now,
                    OptionId = (int)SettingOption.TextFontSize,
                    Value = FillTextSizeOptions().First(m => m.Position == e.Position).Value.ToString(),
                };

                await LangUpDataSaverLoader.SaveUserSettings(newSetting);
                initialTextSizeSpinnerPosition = e.Position;
                LangUpDataSaverLoader.LoadUserSettingsAndFillAppValues();
                dialog.Dismiss();
            }
        }
```

Comment: You need to implement the interface `INotifyPropertyChanged` in your ViewModel .

Comment: I have that, but i dont know how to save the value to the model

Comment: Implement the interface in model at same time .

Comment: I did, i am still getting an error as i cant convert int to Model

Comment: What 's means of `convert int to Model ` ? You can only set the property of Model as the int value .

Comment: For this to work i need to get var customSize = _textSize.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Value == LangUpUserCustomSettings.CustomFontSize).Position; but since the Position is part of the model i am getting an error that i can convert model to int

Comment: I know i cant convert model to int, but i dont know how else to do the method

Comment: can you please be specific about which lines cause the problem and what exact error or exception they are causing?

Comment: I used comment in the code

Comment: have you debugged that LINQ query? does _textSize contain an element that matches your parameters?

Comment: Yes. I have. Once i select the value from the picker the item is null, so the value in the linq is also null.

Comment: The .Position must be somehow there

Comment: I only dont know how

Comment: This is what i have in the output
04-20 17:09:27.151 W/InputEventReceiver(27643): Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.

Comment: Could you share a sample so that I can test it on my side .

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT i am on it, where can i share it?

Comment: Upload it to github .

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/33whpu3wvsq0y25/pickertest.zip?dl=0

Comment: sorry couldnt get it to github

Comment: you only uploaded you sln file, not your code

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/1qtncljkh6wrsml/AADDFb7BsNwUrAp_g3tPazELa?dl=0

Comment: I also updated the question

Comment: that just contains your core project, there is no way to run it without the platform projects